# Can I add border margin into beamer frame body

Tags: beamer, margins, geometry

In default, `beamer` class loads the `geometry` package. And I dont know how to map the `\paperwidth` and `\textwidth` to its mechanism. My requirement is very simple. I want to add some margin to {top, left, bottom, right}. Do you know how to do that?

For simplification, I upload a sketch image:

[image]

Can I do this with `\setbeamersize` command?

Edit: Thank you for your answer. But can I do this  with no walk-around way. I mean can I just customize beamer class. I also need to separate  header/body/footer to customize. I dont want to cron them or zoom them as whole document

Comment: Maybe the `pgfpages` package (not `pdfpages`) might help you here. It is from the same author as `beamer` and often used for handouts etc. where you need to modify the logical page (2 on 1 etc.)

Comment: Do you want to keep the original size for the content and add additional margin, thereby increasing the paper size or do you want to reduce the used size while keeping the original paper size?

Comment: @MartinScharrer I edited my answer to point out that `crop` can be used in both cases.

Comment: After reading your question several times, I can't understand what's the request. `:-(`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `\geometry` plus the [`crop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/crop) package. This way, `beamer` will assume a smaller paper size and correctly place frame titles, header/footer etc.

EDIT: In the following example, I have kept `beamer`'s original paper size of 128*96mm for `crop`, while reducing the width and height by 10mm each for `beamer`/`\geometry`. One could also increase the width and height used by `crop` and retain the original values for `beamer`/`\geometry` (by simply omitting the respective code line).

EDIT 2: For different top/bottom margins one may replace `crop`'s center option with its underlying code and tinker with the `\voffset` length.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\geometry{paperwidth=118mm,paperheight=86mm}
\usepackage[width=128mm,height=96mm,frame,noinfo]{crop}

% The following is moelled on `crop`'s `center` option
\voffset\stockheight
\advance\voffset-\paperheight
\voffset.33\voffset% instead of .5\voffset
\hoffset\stockwidth
\advance\hoffset-\paperwidth
\hoffset.5\hoffset

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work, can you show you border or fill the frame body with certain background

Comment: @pythonee The frame visible left and right in the new picture is the "inner" border. If that's not what you want, please update and clarify your question.

Comment: I have uploaded new image to illustrate what I want. As Martin said I want reduce the used size while keeping the original paper size

Comment: @pythonee That's exactly what the complete example in my answer does.

Comment: But how can I define different top-margin and bottom-margin

Answer (score 1):

Let `presentation.pdf` be your slide document.

The following code will import the slide and enclose each page with a border.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{etoolbox,ifpdf,ifxetex}

\ifxetex
    \newcount\pdflastximagepages
    \def\pdfximage#1{\pdflastximagepages=\XeTeXpdfpagecount"#1"\relax}
\fi

\usepackage[active,tightpage,graphics]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=12pt

\begin{document}
\pdfximage{Presentation.pdf}
\multido{\i=1+1}{\the\pdflastximagepages}{\includegraphics[page=\i]{Presentation}}
\end{document}
```

Compile it with either `pdflatex` or `xelatex`.

**Without border:**

[image]

**With borders:**

[image]

Comment: Note that with this approach, the link buttons no longer work. :-)

Comment: Look at my reversion question